# python class inheritance tree

Tags: python, oop

Suppose I have this classes:

```
class a(object): 
    pass
class b(a):
    pass
class c(b): 
    pass
class d(c): 
    pass
class e(b):
    pass
```

I want a function that will do somthing like:

```
>>>get_ inheritance_tree(a)
>>>...b
>>>......c
>>>.........d
>>>......e
```

Comment: I will be glad for a tool like that.

Comment: note: in python3 [sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/inheritance.html) can create inheritance diagrams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily for you, such visualization tools already exist.

One of them is [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/). You can run a command like:

```
% epydoc -v --graph=classtree mymodule1.py [mymodule2.py ...]
```

Among the useful files it will generate, you'd find `class-tree.html`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more beautiful version of the [Hugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54614686/14627505):

```py
def class_tree(cls):
    return { cls.__name__: [class_tree(sub_class) for sub_class in cls.__subclasses__()] }


def print_tree(tree, indent=4, current_ind=0):
    for k, v in tree.items():
        if current_ind:
            before_dashes = current_ind - indent
            print(' ' * before_dashes + '└' + '-'*(indent-1) + k)
        else:
            print(k)
        for sub_tree in v:
            print_tree(sub_tree, indent=indent, current_ind=current_ind + indent)
```

Result:

```py
>>> ct = class_tree(a)
>>> print_tree(ct, indent=4)
a
└---b
    └---c
        └---d
    └---e
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need visualisation but do need a tree, there is a simple way to do it if you represent the tree by a nested list of branch `[object, [children]]` and leaves `[object, [[]]]`.

Then, by defining the recursive function:

```
def classTree(cls): # return all subclasses in form of a tree (nested list)
    return [cls, [[b for c in cls.__subclasses__() for b in classTree(c)]]]
```

You can get the inheritance tree:

```
>>> classTree(A)
[<class 'A'>, [[<class 'B'>, [[<class 'C'>, [[<class 'D'>, [[]]]], <class 'E'>, [[]]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about graphical presentation and need a list of children, then a recursive function could be used to prepare the list:

```
def get_all_subclasses(class_to_analize):
    all_subclasses = []
    for subclass in class_to_analize.__subclasses__():
        all_subclasses.append(subclass)
        all_subclasses.extend(get_all_subclasses(subclass))

    return all_subclasses

print(get_all_subclasses(a))
```

The output will be:

```
[<class '__main__.b'>, <class '__main__.c'>, <class '__main__.d'>, <class '__main__.e'>]
```